# How to send direct input to another program on windows?

Tags: c#, input

*If you have used [GameRanger](https://www.gameranger.com/), you will better understand this question.*

I want to send a direct input, like keystrokes and mouse clicks, to another program (given that I know its executable) on Windows.

So far, I've been using .NET's SendKeys class, according to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

The program that I'm targeting is another .NET application, but I was having a lot of trouble, as it opens a large number of windows, with random handles every time (and names). Thus, I couldn't figure out a way to reliably verify that the particular window that I wanted was open. My solution was relying on the user to have it open, and having focused the correct input control, then my application sending alt+tab and writing its thing with SendWait*.

It does work fine most of the time, but it's the very antithesis of robustness. GameRanger does a similar thing, but much better. How can I achieve the same reliability? Any method/library that can run on windows is ok, if it's in C#, the better.

*Sometimes, a SendWait call might get lost; I haven't forced the new implementation as instructed in the msdn article, I will try it if nothing better exists.

Comment: This question is too broad.  Can narrow it down to a specific question?  Questions asking for a third-party library or resource are off topic too.

Comment: Get old Petzold's book "Programming Windows", old version, before windows 8. And there are a lot of informations about how Windows handles messages and how to do it.

Comment: I know about 3rd party libraries, I don't know if it's too broad to ask how to reliably send input to another window...  I'll certainly check the book ty.

Comment: Would [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx) work for you? It would mean moving up a semantic level (instead of "click mouse at these coordinates", it's more along the line of "find button labelled X and have it invoke its Click behaviour")